# Can I query list items from two different lists in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, list, caml-query, ajax

I'm just wondering if it's possible to query list items from two different lists using Ajax in SharePoint 2010. I know it's possible to use Designer, however, I need this ability outside of Designer (i.e. with C#/jQuery Ajax).

I also know it's possible to query a SharePoint list and add the results to an ArrayList, then query the second SharePoint list and add those results to the same ArrayList. Is there any other way using CamlQuery or SPQuery?

Answer (score -1):

The other option you can use is search. Now for 2010 it is more complex since it is not exposed via REST services. Here is a blog post that may help you out:
http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2011/08/31/sharepoint-2010-search-via-rest.aspx

Comment: WE DON'T SEE THE LINK !

Comment: sorry it looks like that post was taken down .... i'll try to find another one for you